# how to check if condition on resize of the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries

I have a menu item login markup that displays differently on mobile via media queries and also if the user is logged in.

LargeDevice - loggedin - ShowMarkup

LargeDevice - loggedOut - ShowMarkup

SmallDevice - loggedin - ShowMarkup

SmallDevice - loggedOut - **DoNotShowMarkup**

The condition of the markup is in an API and so I have an if condition to check if the user is logged out like this

```
  if (acs.user.loggedin === false) {
            $('a.navbar-toggle.icon').hide();
            $('#my-menu').show();
     }
```

The rest of it is done with CSS only and works as expected.

The only problem is if the user is logged out and is on a LargeDevice and then resizes to a small screen. How can I tell the browser to check if the browser width is resized to recheck for the `acs.user.loggedin` or some other solution for this problem?

Comment: window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction); check the size and login state in the function.

Comment: @Radio: There is no need for that.

Comment: oh, ok. perhaps i misunderstood the issue.

Comment: @SLaks then? I think here html markup only rendered based on condition. So by only using CSS this may not be possible and need to handle using resize event.

Comment: @TechnoCrat: No.  Always render the markup, then hide it using media queries & CSS classes.

Comment: ya @TechnoCrat is correct, i have to check the js object conditions if its for the 4th scenario

Comment: @SLaks yes that way possible as u have given solution. But I am saying by only JavaScript based upon current HTML markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of showing and hiding elements directly from Javascript, change your JS code to add a CSS `logged-in` or `logged-out` classes to a container element.

You can then use CSS selectors with that classname, in and out of media queries, to specify your four states:

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
   .logged-out a.navbar-toggle.icon {
       display: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: but the logged and logged out only class can only be checked via js

Comment: @nolawipetros: You can add the CSS class to the element in JS, then control its visibility using CSS.

Comment: GOT IT. I am trying that now!

Comment: adding a logged-out class works the same... as i had previously. no changes because .. i can only check the status once on my end. I can't fix the api

Comment: @nolawipetros: Huh? I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: there is one scenario in which if the user is loggedout  on a large screen then logs in and then resizes the browser to be small screen the loggedout class is still present. The page does not refresh- I can only check to see if the user is loggedin or out once on my end. Thus I need something to check on page resize...

Comment: @nolawipetros: But the media query will no longer match, so it will vanish automatically.  Use CSS.

Comment: didnt solve the issue but I have fixed it.. somewhat with the above solution.